# Business Rule errors not going away when data is valid

Tags: wpf, validation, catel

I am using Orc.FluentValidation and I have:

```
[ValidatorDescription(nameof(Customer), ValidationResultType.Error,
    Orc.FluentValidation.ValidationType.BusinessRule)]
public class CustomerBusinessRuleValidator : AbstractValidator<Customer>
{
    public CustomerBusinessRuleValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Addresses).Must(x => x != null && x.Count > 0 && x.Any(add => add.IsCurrent))
            .WithMessage("Customer object is required to have at least 1 current address.");
    }
}
```

`CustomerAddress`

```
public class CustomerAddress : Entity
{
    [DomainSignature] public Address Address { get; set; }

    [DomainSignature] public Lookup AddressType { get; set; }

    [DomainSignature] public bool IsCurrent { get; set; }


}
```

`Customer`

```
public class Customer : Entity
{
    [DomainSignature]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public Gender Gender { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public Lookup PlaceOfBirth { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CustomerAddress> Addresses { get; set; }

    public Lookup Occupation { get; set; }

    public IdDocument Id1 { get; set; }

    public IdDocument Id2 { get; set; }

}
```

On the View even after a `CustomerAddress` with `IsCurrent = true` is added for the `Customer`, the message still shows. Also, I am not sure why some field-bound controls show the error and others not _this is not a field validation rule.

Is there like a method call to be done after adding the `CustomerAddress` to the `Addresses` collection?

i.imgur.com/eecAFuJ.png

Comment: If the collection is not an `ObservableCollection` or a `BindingList` then changes to it cannot be detected automatically. However, I never worked with validators.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you raise a property changed on the whole collection for error validation (e.g. RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(MyCollection)), otherwise the UI can't update the validation results.

> Also, I am not sure why some field-bound controls show the error and
>   others not _this is not a field validation rule.

This is *probably* because of the default styles you are using. For most of the controls, Orchestra creates an error template (decorator), but not every control had this. We've been working on adding these last week, so I recommend to try out the latest alpha of Orchestra & Orc.Controls.

Also make sure to set `ValidateOnDataErrors` and `NotifyOnValidationErrors` on the binding to show the validation in the UI.